# mostrar el calculo de ingresando datos en dos input diferentes y mostrar el resultado en otro input automaticamnte

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Registro de Pedidos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'mostrar.php';">Ir a Nueva Página</button>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Registro de Pedidos</h2>
  <form id="pedidoForm" action="procesar.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" required>
        <option value="en_ruta">En Ruta</option>
        <option value="en_tienda">En Tienda</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombreTienda">Nombre de la Tienda:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreTienda" name="nombreTienda" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="courier">Courier:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="courier" name="courier" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombreCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCliente" name="nombreCliente" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total">Total del Paquete:</label>
      <input type="number" name="total" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="delivery">PRECIO Delivery:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="delivery" name="delivery" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Pago del Delivery por la Tienda:</label>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="pagoDeliverySi" name="pagoDelivery" value="si" 
          required onchange="updateGanancia()">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="pagoDeliverySi">Sí</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="pagoDeliveryNo" name="pagoDelivery" value="no" 
          required onchange="updateGanancia()">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="pagoDeliveryNo">No</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gananciaTienda">Ganancia de la Tienda:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gananciaTienda" name="gananciaTienda" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="observacion">Observación:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="observacion" name="observacion"></textarea>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.0.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Esta función se ejecuta cuando la página ha sido completamente cargada

    function updateGanancia() {
      var totalElement = document.getElementById('total');
      var deliveryElement = document.getElementById('delivery');
      var pagoDeliverySiElement = document.getElementById('pagoDeliverySi');
      var gananciaTiendaElement = document.getElementById('gananciaTienda');

      if (totalElement && deliveryElement && pagoDeliverySiElement && gananciaTiendaElement) {
        var totalPaquete = parseFloat(totalElement.value) || 0;
        var precioDelivery = parseFloat(deliveryElement.value) || 0;
        var pagoDeliverySi = pagoDeliverySiElement.checked;

        var gananciaTienda = pagoDeliverySi ? totalPaquete : precioDelivery - totalPaquete;

        gananciaTiendaElement.value = gananciaTienda.toFixed(2);
      }
    }

    // Llama a la función cuando la página se carga por primera vez para reflejar los valores iniciales
    updateGanancia();

    // Asocia la función con el evento input en los campos relevantes
    var totalElement = document.getElementById('total');
    var deliveryElement = document.getElementById('delivery');
    var pagoDeliverySiElement = document.getElementById('pagoDeliverySi');
    var pagoDeliveryNoElement = document.getElementById('pagoDeliveryNo');

    if (totalElement) totalElement.addEventListener('input', updateGanancia);
    if (deliveryElement) deliveryElement.addEventListener('input', updateGanancia);
    if (pagoDeliverySiElement) pagoDeliverySiElement.addEventListener('input', updateGanancia);
    if (pagoDeliveryNoElement) pagoDeliveryNoElement.addEventListener('input', updateGanancia);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Buenos dias
estoy queriendo lograr lo siguinte
tengo este codigo necesito que realice la siguinte funionalidad dinamica al agregar el monto en el input Total del Paquete y luego el dato en el input PRECIO Delivery: hacer el siguinte calculo de acuerdo si se selecciona Pago del Delivery por la Tienda se "si" o "no", en el caso que se selecciones "si" debe mostrar en el input Ganancia de la Tienda: automaticamente el monto de Total del Paquete  si se selecciona "no" debe mostrar la resta de PRECIO Delivery: menos Total del Paquete:
Es un control para una tienda que de courier porque lo que ocurre es lo siguinte el delivery va a retirar de la tienda el paquete y puede ocurrir dos cosas
1° Si el radio buton es "si" la tienda le puede pagar el costo del envio al delivery al momento de pasar a buscar el paquete en este caso hipotetico supongamos que el paquete cuesta 150.000 y el envio 20.000 entonces el courier cuando entregue el paquete le tiene que rendir a la tienda solo los 145.000
2° Si el radio Buton es "no" el mismo caso pero si la tienda no paga el envio el delivery le cobra al cliente los 20.000 y eso descuenta de los 150.000 que quedaria 130.000 para rendir a la tienda

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que entendi es esto, si necesitas ajustalo a tus necesidades, solo cambie los radio buttons por una lista desplegable lo senti mas comodo asi.. prueba y me avisas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Registro de Pedidos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'mostrar.php';">Ir a Nueva Página</button>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Registro de Pedidos</h2>
  <form id="pedidoForm" action="procesar.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" required>
        <option value="en_ruta">En Ruta</option>
        <option value="en_tienda">En Tienda</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombreTienda">Nombre de la Tienda:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreTienda" name="nombreTienda" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="courier">Courier:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="courier" name="courier" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombreCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCliente" name="nombreCliente" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total">Total del Paquete:</label>
      <input type="number" name="total" id="total" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="delivery">PRECIO Delivery:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="delivery" name="delivery" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Pago del Delivery por la Tienda:</label>
        <select id="pagodelivery" class="form-control" onchange="revpre()">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">Si</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gananciaTienda">Ganancia de la Tienda:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gananciaTienda" name="gananciaTienda" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="observacion">Observación:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="observacion" name="observacion"></textarea>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.0.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
function revpre(){
    let delivery = $('#pagodelivery').val();
    
    if (delivery == '1'){
    let ganancia = $('#gananciaTienda').val(); 
    let total = $('#total').val();    
    $('#gananciaTienda').val(total);
    }
    else if(delivery == '0'){
    let predelivery = $('#delivery').val();
    let total = $('#total').val();

    let resultado = predelivery - total;
    $('#gananciaTienda').val(resultado);

    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```